# Webpage with Javascript executing Python script with arguments

Tags: javascript, python, html, arguments

I have three files in the same directory. One is a python script, which takes argumenet. One is a html page with javascript. And the last one is a source .wav file.

```
./myfolder/sound_manipulation.py
./myfolder/volume_slider.html
./myfolder/the_song.wav
```

The sound_manipulation.py file can be executed like:

```
python sound_manipulation.py -v 50
```

and it generates a new wav file, new_song.wav, based on the_song.wav, but only has 50% of the original volume level.

On the other hand, the volume_slider.html contains a slider goes from 0 to 100%, and a button calling an onclick javascript function, update_vol();

So far, the update_vol() alerts the value of the slider, and that's all.

```
function update_vol() {
    var vol = document.getElementById('vol_slider').value;
    alert(vol);
}
```

But I want the update_vol() to actually execute the python script using the vol.

How can I make that happen?

Also, when the "python sound_manipulation.py -v 50" is executed, how can I return the location of the new_song.wav back to volume_slider.html?

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and crudest one-time cgi script might solve your problem.

set up a cgi script/environment to just get `volume` value from user / then use `subprocess` module to process the .wav file and send it back to user. if you need anything more than that, build your own web app.

```
import cgi
import subprocess
import sys
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
volume = form.getfirst('volume') #read from form 'volume'

subprocess.call(['python', 'sound_manipulation.py', '-v', volume])

with open('new_song.wav', 'rb') as wav_file:
    print("Content-Type: audio/wav\n")
    sys.stdout.write(wav_file.read())
```

Comment: Thank you. I will see if I can get the server ready to handle this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, well, I guess you're out of luck. Browser scripts *can't* execute anything (so no Python script) on your system. As I'm sure you can imagine, this could present a huge security risk -- that's exactly how much trouble Microsoft's ActiveX got into.

I'm assuming you want to create a graphical interface for that script, so alternatively you could :

- Do a JavaScript equivalent of your Python script if you absolutely need HTML
- Or create an interface in QT, GTK or the like. Python can easily do that, by the way!